# Is it possible to use oracle.managed.dataaccess with oracle client 11.2.03 32bit?

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

### Edit (Working Solution Found!):

> For some reason my app would not pick up the tnsname file, unless I
>   removed the other naming methods from .ora file (order of naming methods, tnsnames, EZCONNECT, LDAP), as you can see the order of precedence is correct. I did not want to remove the those naming methods from the sqlnet.ora file
>   but by adding the following setting
>   suggested by Dan Keller in conjunction with the TNS_ADMIN setting I already
>   had, Oracle was able to pick up the TNS name file.
>   so to clarify setting element looks like this,

```
<settings>
        <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="TNSNAMES"></setting>
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="d:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\"/>                
</settings>
```

I have a web app

I've downloaded the following Oracle managed data access from Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/12.1.22

the current oracle client on development server is 11.2.0.3 32bit

I've set up my web.config to include the following

```
  <settings>

    <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="d:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_\network\admin"/>


  </settings>

</version>
```

But I get the following error:

The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution' threw an exception.

Any advice? Thanks.

[Edit]
here's some more info in the exception

The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution' threw an exception.
   at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution.Resolve(String TNSAlias, ConnectionOption& CO, String instanceName)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.ResolveTnsAlias(ConnectionString cs)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Initialize(ConnectionString cs)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Initialize(ConnectionString cs)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.GetPM(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, Boolean& bAuthenticated, Boolean& newPM)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()

Comment: What is the exception? What is the chain of `InnerException` property values? What are the messages?

Comment: Oracle Managed has no dependency on having an Oracle Client installed. That's the beauty of it.

Comment: posted some more info on exception above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle Managed does not use a TNS Name file instead a custom Configuration section in the app/web.config file. You can connect to an Oracle 11 database using the Oracle 12 managed driver. The managed drive will ignore the 11g 32 bit that is previously installed.

One thing to note the managed drive will not work with Oracle User Defined Types.

```
<configuration>
    <system.data>
            <DbProviderFactories>
                <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
                <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
                    type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
            </DbProviderFactories>
        </system.data>


      <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
            <version number="*">
                <dataSources>
                    <dataSource alias="DEV11"
                        descriptor=" (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DEV11SVR)(PORT = 1525)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = dev11)))"/>
                </dataSources>
            </version>
        </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Comment: according the documentation I think I should, http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/ODPnet/index.html#section2s3 (forgive if I'm wrong I'm a newbie)

Comment: Do I just copy and paste whats in my tsnnames file?

Comment: Yes just copy and paste

Comment: awesome that work, but wonder why you cant specify tns name file? Did I misread what's the oracle docs say?

Comment: To be honest, the documenation you found from oracle is newer than  when I put together my managed client code, I used what I sent you. Things might have changed since, I did this 6 months ago. I never ran across this documentation that you found.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your SQLNET.ORA file, it could be that it's finding the TNSNames file from the oracle 11 install, but the oracle 11 is configured to check LDAP or EZConnect before it checks TNSNames.

You can override this setting without having to manually enter what is in the TNSNames, which is the benefit of using the TNSNames file if for example your organization changes servers and the database group manages the TNSNames file.

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
        <settings>
            <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="TNSNAMES"></setting>
        </settings>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

Comment: should it look like this? <setting name="d:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin" value="TNSNAMES"></setting> tried, but does not seem to work

Comment: This is what's found in the .ORA file # SQLNET.ORA Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = WORLD

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)



NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (tnsnames, EZCONNECT, LDAP)

Comment: Looks like the setting for DIRECTORY_PATH is correct in that order. Needs more info on the inner exception, as per above.